# hibernate-validator-5.3.6.Final.jar' in project 'SpringRest' cannot be read

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-boot

I am trying to run a sample REST project that is under Spring-Boot.

I am using Eclipse Oxygen.

**here is the pom.xml file**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.sample</groupId>
    <artifactId>SpringRest</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>SpringRest</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-web -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.9.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

**I also have the following as part of the installation:**

```
C:\Users\dgmufasa>mvn -version
Apache Maven 3.2.2 (45f7c06d68e745d05611f7fd14efb6594181933e; 2014-06-17T08:51:42-05:00)
Maven home: C:\WORK\Software\Maven\apache-maven-3.2.2
Java version: 1.8.0_161, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: C:\WORK\Software\Java8JDK\jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 10", version: "10.0", arch: "amd64", family: "dos"

C:\Users\dgmufasa>javac -version
javac 1.8.0_161

C:\Users\dgmufasa>java -version
java version "1.8.0_161"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_161-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 25.161-b12, mixed mode, sharing)
```

**When I run the code, I get the following**

> Archive for required library:
>   'C:/Users/dgmufasa/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-validator/5.3.6.Final/hibernate-validator-5.3.6.Final.jar'
>   in project 'SpringRest' cannot be read or is not a valid ZIP file

I have done a "maven update" but the problem still persists.

What can I do?

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar problems occured to me sometimes when the connection to my maven proxy (I am using Nexus) is not ideal and the jar files are corrupt.

Delete c:/Users/dgmufasa/.m2/repository content and it will be synchronized again.

You can also try to delete only 5.3.6.Final directory first ;-)

Comment: Hi - that did work for the most part. I just got rid of the whole thing. I had to do several deletes of the repository and updates because of SLFJ issues. Now, the intellisese is not working and I am on the hunt to see why,

Comment: Window -> Preferences -> Download Artifact sources & Download Artifacts switched on does not helped ? probably your .m2 repository is not in well condition and needs resynchronizing by maven update